# I write this code in cpanel then run the website,but the website cannot be reached

Tags: php

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "xxx");
define("DB_PASS", "xxx");
define("DB_NAME", "xxx");


$connection= @mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected= @mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Database Selection Failed! : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

how to solve the problem in connectivity error in php code. any error in this code

Comment: Don't suppress errors. Remove all the  `@`.

Comment: To start with, you should stop using the `mysql_*`-api since they were deprecated back in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use Mysqli or PDO instead. You should also remove all `@` (suppressing errors) since that will make your debugging _a lot_ harder (since you won't see the actual errors). Make sure that you have error reporting turned on and check you web servers error log for clues.

Comment: i remove the @ but that page is not working.

Comment: Then go check the error logs first of all.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_ function are deprecated and no longer supported from PHP 7.0 and above.
Therefore, if you are using any other PHP version you get an error.

Also, please be sure that your server is running.

I can't find any typo or error in your code.

Please remove @ (suppress error) and post your error so I can help you.

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers. These are just stabs in the dark since we have _no idea_ what the actual errors are.